# this keyword value when using React event handlers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

Why is the value of `this` in an event handler's callback different when using React?

For instance, when adding an event handler to an element in JS, the value of `this` in the callback function is always the element upon which the handler is placed (assuming arrow functions are not used for callbacks). So, we have this:

```
button.onclick = function(event) {
  alert(this); // [object HTMLButtonElement]
}
```

However, if I do the same thing in React:

```
<button onClick={function() {
  alert(this); // undefined
  }
}>
</button>
```

... as you can see, `this` refers to `undefined` rather than the button element.

Could this be an implication of "JSX callbacks"? Is it just a React thing?

Comment: React probably doesn't want you to interact with the DOM element at all, that's why they don't pass it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is react thing. If you want to get the button element, please do this:

```
<button onClick={function(e) {
  alert(e.target);
  }
}>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`React.Component` doesn't auto bind methods to itself. You need to bind them yourself in constructor. If you use arrow function, you don't need to bind because its context is the same.

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  
  this.state = {
    loopActive: false,
    shuffleActive: false,
  };
  
  this.onToggleLoop = this.onToggleLoop.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am aware of the need to bind methods, was just wondering why the value of `this` differed in React.

Comment: @Prime You can use `this` to get the context of React component by binding the methods. But what @tulate is asking is to get the context of button element. It seems like that @Thunderbolt Engineer's answer is correct.